# Create a login page. but do not fetch and login

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Create a login page. First is put a name and password then move a another xib (another view). name and password already save in a CoreData (data base). I'm used a fetch query through fetch data (name and password) and move to another xib.

```
- (IBAction)loginbtn:(id)sender
{

    [self.tx1 resignFirstResponder];

    [self.tx2 resignFirstResponder];

    if (self.tx1.text.length == 0)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter User Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if (self.tx2.text.length == 0)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    }

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Loginform" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@ AND password==%@",self.tx1.text, self.tx2.text];

[request setEntity:entity];

[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

NSLog(@"The returned results are %@",results);

for (Loginform *anAccount in results)
{
    if ([anAccount.name isEqualToString:self.tx1.text])
    {

        NSLog(@"Your username exists");

        if ([anAccount.password isEqualToString:self.tx2.text])
        {

            NSLog(@"Your pin is correct");

            if([anAccount.name isEqualToString:@"root"])
            {
                homeViewController*home = [[homeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:Nil];

                [self presentViewController:home animated:YES completion:Nil];

            }
            else 
            {

                NSLog(@"Your pin is wrong");
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

                [alert show];

            }

        }
        else
        {

             NSLog(@"Your username was not found");

             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter User Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

             [alert show];

        }

    }

}

}
```

Comment: can't understand your issue , please explain your issue clearly, as per your coding part is clear

Comment: Edit my que. please again read and solve my problem.

Comment: what's the error you are getting??

Comment: can you show your save data functionality??

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)loginbtn:(id)sender
{

    [self.tx1 resignFirstResponder];

    [self.tx2 resignFirstResponder];

    if (self.tx1.text.length == 0)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter User Name" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else if (self.tx2.text.length == 0)
    {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Please Enter Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request= [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Loginform" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name==%@ AND password==%@",self.tx1.text, self.tx2.text];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    Loginform *anAccount = results.firstObject;
    if(anAccount!=nil){
        if([anAccount.name is equalToString self.tx1.text && [anAccount.password isEqualToString:self.tx2.text]])
        {
            //login success
            homeViewController*home = [[homeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:Nil];
            [self presentViewController:home animated:YES completion:Nil];
        }else{
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@“Username or password is wrong" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

            [alert show];              
        }
    }
}
```